# Ajax multiple file upload dont work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm usign this code to pass all file input by ajax. There are three input file in html code .But only the first file input be sent by ajax. how to fix this code? Where is my mistake?

```
$("#add_order").click(function () {

    //*****get data input
    var formData = new FormData(); 
        formData.append( 'action', 'add_order');

    $.each($("input[type=file]"), function(i, obj) {
        $.each(obj.files,function(j,file){
            alert(file.name);
            formData.append('orderpic[]', file);
        });
    });

    //ajax start and ajax complatet
    ajax_loading();

    $.ajax({
        url: "includes/ajax/ajax.php",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(response){
           //load json data from server and output message     
           if(response.type == 'error'){ //load json data from server and output message     
               output = '<div class="alert alert-danger" style="margin-top:12px;">'+response.text+'</div>';
           }else{
               output = '<div class="alert alert-success" style="margin-top:12px;">'+response.text+'</div>';
               resetAllValues();
               setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#new-order').modal('hide');
                }, 1500);
           }
           $("#results").hide().html(output).fadeIn('slow').delay(800).fadeOut();
    });        
});
```

HTML code:

```
<input type="file" name="orderpic[]" id="orderpic" class="form-control">
<input type="file" name="orderpic[]" id="orderpic" class="form-control">
<input type="file" name="orderpic[]" id="orderpic" class="form-control">
```

PHP code:

```
//file settings
    $files = array();
    for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['orderpic']['name']); $i++) {
        //Get the temp file path
        $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['orderpic']['tmp_name'][$i];

        //Make sure we have a filepath
        if ($tmpFilePath != "") {
            //Setup our new file path
            $time = time();
            $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['orderpic']['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $FilePath = $uploaddir . $time .'.'. $ext;

            //Upload the file into the temp dir
            if (move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $FilePath)) {
                $resizeObj = new resize($FilePath);
                $resizeObj -> resizeImage(200, 350, 'portrait');
                $newFilePath = $uploaddir. "200_350_" .$time.'.'.$ext;
                $resizeObj -> saveImage($newFilePath, 100);
                unlink($FilePath);
                $files[] = "200_350_" .$time.'.'.$ext;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "don't work"? Are there errors? Have you checked?

Comment: and what does your php code look like? Have you checked the network tab of the developers tools (usually F12) and check the request and see if it is actually sending all files or just one?

Comment: @PatrickEvans I added php code to question.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I checked the console.log() in chrom and i did not receive an error. Another way is to check the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably due to not using is `basename($_FILES['orderpic']['name'][$i])` in `$FilePath` and `$newFilePath`.

Try this:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['orderpic']['name']); $i++) {
        //Get the temp file path
        $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['orderpic']['tmp_name'][$i];

        //Make sure we have a filepath
        if ($tmpFilePath != "") {
            //Setup our new file path
            $time = time();
            $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['orderpic']['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            //$FilePath = $uploaddir . $time .'.'. $ext;
            $FilePath = $uploaddir . $time. basename($_FILES['orderpic']['name'][$i]);

            //Upload the file into the temp dir
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $FilePath)){
                $resizeObj = new resize($FilePath);
                $resizeObj -> resizeImage(200, 350, 'portrait');
                $newFilePath = $uploaddir ."200_350". $time. basename($_FILES['orderpic']['name'][$i]);
                $resizeObj -> saveImage($newFilePath, 100);
                unlink($FilePath);
                $files[] = "200_350". $time. basename($_FILES['orderpic']['name'][$i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

'id' cannot be the same for input controls.  Change it to something like shown in the html below and it should work.

```
    <input type="file" name="orderpic[]" id="orderpic1" class="form-control">
    <input type="file" name="orderpic[]" id="orderpic2" class="form-control">
    <input type="file" name="orderpic[]" id="orderpic3" class="form-control">
```

Comment: While it is true that elements need unique ids, since OP is not using the id to get the elements this does not answer the question.

Comment: This is not a relevant answer!